# How to calculate new X, Y coordinates of a moving object

Tags: trigonometry, physics, parametrization

I am not 100% sure if this is the correct forum for this questions. I am sorry if it is slightly off topic.

I have a grid of 100m x 100m which objects travel from one position $(x_1, y_1)$ to another $(x_2, y_2)$. The objects move at 5 m/s. I have managed to calculate the distance between both points using the euclidean distance formula, but i am struggling with calculating the current x & y positions every second.

For example, if an object starts at $(15, 27)$ and is travelling to $(80, 10)$, how would i calculate the current $(x, y)$ coordinates after 1 sec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, because your object is traveling with constant velocity, you can easily parameterize the motion in independent directions as follows. Notice the entire motion will travel the distance of $$d = \sqrt{(80-15)^2 + (10-27)^2} = \sqrt{4514} \approx 67.19 \text{m}$$ with speed $v = 5 \text{m/sec}$, which must happen over a total time of $$T = \frac{d}{v} \approx 13.44 \text{sec}.$$

Thus speed in $x$ is $$v_x = \frac{\Delta x}{T} = \frac{65}{T}$$ and in $y$ it must be $$v_y = \frac{\Delta y}{T} = \frac{10-27}{T} = \frac{-17}{T}.$$

Now you can parameterize:
$$
x(t) = x_0 + v_x t = 15 + \frac{65t}{T}\\
y(t) = y_0 + v_y t = 27 - \frac{17t}{T}.
$$

As a check on our work, note that $x(0) = x_0 = 15$ and $y(0) = y_0 = 27$, as trivially expected, but more importantly, $x(T) = 15+65 = 80$ and $y(T) = 27 - 17 = 10$, as required by your original problem statement.